# Twilio Voice associating CallSid with UserID

Tags: twilio

I just don't get how I can keep track on my backend/app that specific users are making specific calls. Right now I am using the BasicPhone app that came with the Android SDK, I have it tied to my backend and all calls are working. I now want to then create my own 'call' history on my backend (using Parse.com)

BackEnd Routes:

```
/token (creates capability for making calls - seems like this is where I pass in who is doing the call??)
/call (create twiml for Dial/Number)
/callstatus (handles status when call is over - intention is to perform some action on my backend to uupdate the specfic user account that started the call)
```

I can't use From/To numbers for ID, since all users will be sharing a set of FromNumbers.

I am logging the request from Twilio on the `/call` POST and only see:

> {"AccountSid":"------","ApplicationSid":"---","Caller":"client:Anonymous","CallStatus":"ringing","Called":"","To":"","CallSid":"-----","From":"client:Anonymous","Direction":"inbound","ApiVersion":"2010-04-01"}

Seems like this is where I can tie a specific user to a CallSid on Twilio, but my "Caller" is always "client:Anonymous"

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

You don't have to use `client:Anonymous`. If you go through the Android SDK quickstart you can see how naming works:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/make-outgoing-call

Specifically you can add [optional params](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#connect) that will get sent to the Twilio application - ([TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications)) associated with a Device's [capability token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) like so:

```
var connection = Twilio.Device.connect({
  agent: "Smith",
  location: "Matrix"
});
```

Hope this proves to be helpful.

Comment: What I don't understand is why isn't the From ever populated, even when the call is from a JavaScrip client setup with a known identifier.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easily faked to pose as another user? Why not have the Twilio API access the username used when the token was generated, and pass it along to our application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set clientName when you are creating your Capability Token in OutgoingClientScope:

```
  try {
    const capability = new ClientCapability({
      accountSid,
      authToken,
      ttl: 43200,
    });
    capability.addScope(new ClientCapability.IncomingClientScope(name));
    capability.addScope(
      new ClientCapability.OutgoingClientScope({
        applicationSid: ApplicationSid,
        clientName: name
      })
    );
    const token = capability.toJwt();
    return token;
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e);
  }
```